# Getting 'real' time from Windows Phone

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, windows-phone

I have a function in my app where i compare milliseconds from Unix Epoch to the current time from:

```
 DateTime.Now
```

This results in a time different ie: 2mins remaining or 4 mins remaining.

The problem ive found is that some users do not set there clocks correctly on their phone, or put it forward slightly, intentionally.

This causes the calculation above to be incorrect.

Is there a way round this, ie; to read 'real' time from someone. 
The time calculations are done on the phone rather than server side for ease.

Answer (score 6):

IMO your problem is not implementation but design.

User's time can be wrong due to many various reasons: user choice, legal (e.g. in Russia the laws that define time zone & daylight saving change every few years, this way the government reminds people it's still there), or technical (hardware fail, incorrect setup of mobile operator's equipment).

You have 3 options how to fix:

1. Have the server return TimeSpan instead of DateTime.
2. Have the server take client's current time, and return the ETA in client's clock.
3. (most complex, only required for very time-sensitive tasks e.g. something like "Solar+Lunar Eclipse Schedule" app) On startup and activation of your app, negotiate with your server about the time differences between UTC date+time on the client's device, and server's clock.